# Displaying dynamic data using charts and graphs in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, highcharts, google-visualization

I want to display dynamic data via charts,graphs which is retrieved from database. There are various gems available like **highcharts, google graphs, gruff library**, etc. Can anyone please site an example how to retrieve data from database and use it to display charts,graphs using anyone of these gems/libraries ? Any help will useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay here's a perfect example. In an application I recently completed I wanted to get the statistics for all employees and their overtime hours. I also then got the summed total for all employees. I decided to use highcharts. I believe that the best thing going to represent charts and graphs. Has really good [documentation](http://docs.highcharts.com/#home) to back it up as well.

**Controller**

```
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController

 def index
    @users = User.all
    @shifts = Shift.scoped
 end 
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart:{
                        renderTo:'container',
                        type:'column'
                    },
                    title:{
                        text:'<%= Date.today.strftime("%B")%> Overtime'
                    },
                    xAxis:{
                        categories:[

                            '<%= Date.today.strftime("%B")%>'

                        ]
                    }, 
                    yAxis:{
                        min:0,
                        title:{
                            text:'Hours'
                        }
                    },
                    legend:{
                        layout:'vertical',
                        backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
                        align:'left',
                        verticalAlign:'top',
                        x:100,
                        y:70,
                        floating:true,
                        shadow:true
                    },
                    tooltip:{
                        formatter:function () {
                            return '' +
                                    'Hours' + ': ' + this.y;
                        },

                        credits:{
                            text:'SomeText.co.uk',
                            hreft:'http://wwww.putyourlinkhere.co.uk'
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions:{
                        column:{
                            pointPadding:0.4,
                            borderWidth:0
                        }
                    },


                    series:[
                        <%@users.each do |user|%>
                        {
                            name:'<%= user.name%>',
                            data:[<%= user.shift.sum(:overtime)%>]
                        },
                        <% end %>
                        {
                            name:'Total',
                            data: [<%= @shifts.to_a.sum(&:overtime)%>],
                            color:'#FE9D00'
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

From this example you can see that the `series` is what is going to represent your data that you want to display. I loop through all users and output their name along with summing their shift. Further down I then grab the total by getting all shifts and putting it into an array and summing the overtime.

Oh and also you will need to download [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/download) and put all relevant files in your assets.

This should be a good enough example to get you going.

Comment: @David thanks for this answer i will try it when i start to make my app , i would like to ask about if i want to make a finance module and HR module like those in fedena educational system.